# Closing popup only if the form is valid

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, richfaces, richfaces-modal

I want to validate my inputText field, which is in a popupPanel. It should contains only numbers.

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Input:"/>
        <h:inputText id="myID" value="#{myBean.field}"
            validatorMessage="Only numbers">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="([0-9])*$" />
            <rich:validator />
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="msgValidator" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="msgValidator" for="myID" styleClass="text_colorRed" />
</h:form>
```

After all I want to save all with button. If the input is correct I want to close the popup, otherwise I want to re-insert the correct input without closing popup.

```
<a4j:ajaxButton type="submit" value="Save" styleClass="text_weigthBold"
    action="#{myBean.save()}" render="myTable"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('myPopup')}.hide();" execute="@this">
</a4j:ajaxButton>
```

Unfortunately when I type wrong input and click two times on the button, it save the request and close the popup without requesting to input the correct text.

I also used a Java validator but the behavior is still the same.

What can I do to correct this bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're closing popup unconditionally. You must check yourself if validation was OK. In JSF 2.0 you can use [FacesContext#isValidationFailed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed--).

```
<a4j:commandButton execute="@form" value="Save" styleClass="text_weigthBold" 
    oncomplete="if (!#{facesContext.validationFailed}) {#{rich:component('myPopup')}.hide();}"
    action="#{myBean.save}" render="myTable" />
```

To check also other errors you can use `facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal gt 0` or `facesContext.maximumSeverity != null`.

I don't know RF 3.X (and you didn't tell if you're using RF 3 or 4) but it looks like it never had component named `a4j:ajaxButton`, did you mean `a4j:commandButton`? Also note that I've changed `action="#{myBean.save()}"` to `action="#{myBean.save}"` which is corrent.

Comment: I'm using Richfaces 4.2, and yes it's an a4j:commandButton. Unfortunatly also if I use the facesContext.validationFailed the behaviour is not correct because when I type the correct input and save, the popup doesnt close. It call the action and the response is right but the popup remains open. What can I do?

Comment: @travis_91 I've updated my answear. You have to change the execute to `@form` or whatever else you want (i use popupId for this kind of edition in popup), because you have to commit the input (so you can pass the input id as well).

Comment: I've tried to change the execute with @form or the popup's Id but when I click on button it doesnt execute the action and the method of my bean. Do you know why?

Comment: Looks like you don't know what does `execute` param do. You can commit only one field (`myID` in youe example). You didn't paste all of your code, so it's just guessing (I don't know where the button is, where the popup is etc.). The committing button should be in the form you want to commit. You cannot commit one form with button that is placed in another form.

Comment: Also notice that the condition should be if not validation failed then close.

Comment: I deleted the other topic. However the button and the input are in the same form ( in the form there are also others outputText), and yeah, I changed the condition of validation in not validationFailed but it doesn't work. 

<rich:popupPanel>
 
 <div>
  <h:form>
   <a4j:outputPanel>
    <table>
     <tr>
       <h:inputText ... />
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <a4j:commandButton ... />
     </tr>
    </table 
   </a4j:outputPanel>  
  </h:form>
 </div>
</rich:popupPanel>

But when I execute the form or myID of popup the action doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. In the form there were some h:checkbox, I remove the checkboxes and now it works fine. I dont know why the Richfaces checkbox doesn't work correctly but I replace them with HTML checkbox.